# Why Range.End is not changing?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to adjust the range of ContentControl. I use this code:

```
var end1 = x.ContentControl.Range.End;
var count = x.ContentControl.Range.Text.Count() - match.Index;

x.ContentControl.Range.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1 * count);

var end2 = x.ContentControl.Range.End;
```

But unfortunately, it's not working. In my example, count is set to 2, but end1 and end2 are the same - 9. It seems that MoveEnd just doesn't do anything...

I tried also to change link.ContentControl.Range.End, but it doesn't seem to do anything either...

Comment: It's not possible to change the range over which the content control extends. If you were to assign the range of the content control to a `Range` object, then move the `End` of that object, that should change. But what you're code is attempting is not supported by the object model. What, exactly, are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: I have a ContentControl which is set on specific text (i.e. "Ala ma kota") and I want to shrink it, so it would be set only on part of it (i.e. "Ala ma", and " kota" should be normal text after ContentControl). I guess the best way would be to remove existing ContentControl and create a new one?

Comment: That would be one possibility. I'd probably opt for leaving the content control alone and moving the text outside the content control, however.